# How to sort argv tab with qsort and strcmp?

Tags: c, sorting, c-strings, strcmp, qsort

My qsort seems to not be sorting anything.
When I pass strings to the program it doesn't sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpstr(const void *a, const void *b){
    char const *aa = (char const *)a;
    char const *bb = (char const *)b;
    
    return strcmp(aa,bb);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    qsort(argv, argc, sizeof(*argv), cmpstr);
    for(int i =0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
}
```

Comment: What **does** it do?

Comment: It is supposed to sort call arguments alphabetically but now it just prints them on stdout

Comment: When you run into problems like this, add diagnostic printing code.  For example, print the strings that are being compared.  When you see gibberish, you know you've got something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

the compare functions is called with *pointers to members* of the array to be sorted. In your case, the array members are of type `char *` so `char **` is passed to `cmpstr()`.
So what you have to do is:

```
int cmpstr(const void *a, const void *b){
    char const **aa = a;
    char const **bb = b;
    
    return strcmp(*aa,*bb);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comparison function should look like

```
int cmpstr(const void *a, const void *b){
    char const *aa = *(char const **)a;
    char const *bb = *(char const **)b;
    
    return strcmp(aa,bb);
}
```

That is the function `qosrt` passes to the comparison function pointers to elements of the sorted array. In the given code the elements have the type `char *`. Pointers to elements have the type `char **`. So to get elements you need to dereference pointers of the type `char **`.

Here is a demonstration program. The following arguments are supplied to the program

```
"f" "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
```

Within the program I excluded the element `argv[0]` because the corresponding string can be too long in some systems. `argv[0]` points to the program name.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int cmpstr( const void *a, const void *b ) {
    char const *aa = *( char const ** )a;
    char const *bb = *( char const ** )b;

    return strcmp( aa, bb );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", argv[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    qsort( argv + 1, argc - 1, sizeof( *argv ), cmpstr );

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" ", argv[i] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

The program output is

```
"f" "e" "d" "c" "b" "a"
"a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why?